# trouble linking boost after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, shared-library, boost

After upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, I started receiving this error whenever I tried to do anything related to postgis:

`could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.2.so": libboost_thread.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I don't have `libboost_thread.so.1.58.0` but I do have `libboost_thread.so.1.61.0` located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. I thought maybe dropping the extension and reinstalling postgis would do the trick, but that didn't seem to change anything. Now, when I try `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` I get the same error.

Output for `ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.2.so | grep libboost`:

```
libboost_thread.so.1.58.0 => not found
libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => not found
libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0 => not found
```

And `ldconfig -p | grep -E "libboost_(thread|system|serialization)"`:

```
libboost_thread.so.1.61.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.61.0
libboost_thread.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so
libboost_system.so.1.61.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.61.0
libboost_system.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
libboost_serialization.so.1.61.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.61.0
libboost_serialization.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so
```

I tried using `LD_PRELOAD` and the correct versions showed up in `ldd`, but it still asked for `1.58.0` on execution.  I haven't found any versions of `1.58.0` installed on the machine, and it's not even available in the default repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out in `/usr/local/lib` I had some `.so` files related to sfcgal(a postgis dependency) that were built prior to upgrading when I was still using the older version of boost.  This directory must have had precedence over the correct directory, and so it was trying to link to the old boost.

I think this should only be a problem for people who built sfcgal from source at some point and didn't clean everything up.